# External variables used in acc routine need to be in #pragma acc create(

Tags: openacc

I'm trying to compile a program in OpenACC and I'm having the following errors

NVC++-W-1056-External variables used in acc routine need to be in #pragma acc create() - i (sim_xy1.c: 1011)
NVC++-W-1056-External variables used in acc routine need to be in #pragma acc create() - j (sim_xy1.c: 1001)
NVC++-W-1056-External variables used in acc routine need to be in #pragma acc create() - j (sim_xy1.c: 993)
NVC++-W-1056-External variables used in acc routine need to be in #pragma acc create() - i (sim_xy1.c: 985)
NVC++-S-1065-Unsupported nested compute construct in compute construct or acc routine (sim_xy1.c: 976)
NVC++-S-1065-Unsupported nested compute construct in compute construct or acc routine (sim_xy1.c: 1028)
NVC++-S-1065-Unsupported nested compute construct in compute construct or acc routine (sim_xy1.c: 1042)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNMMA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQpp.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide a minimal reproducing example, it will be much easier to help.  There's a lot of missing context since the code you screen shot is incomplete.  However, this message may be the key:

```
NVC++-S-1065-Unsupported nested compute construct in compute construct or acc routine (sim_xy1.c: 1042)
```

This implies that you're nesting parallel loops and hence I assume that  "produto_matriz_vetor" is a device routine is being called from this region?

Global variables in acc routines need to have a global device reference, in this case the loop index variables.

Note device vector routines can't use "parallel", but just the "loop" directive.

Comment: Suggested edit: "Note device vector routines *can't* use "parallel", but just the "loop" directive"